# How to Apply Color LUT to bitmap images for filter effects in android?

Tags: android, bitmap, lookup-tables

here i have a question on LUTs in android.

my question is, i have 4X4 LUTs, Using these LUTs apply filter effect for bitmap image in android. Below is my sample LUT file link.
[Lut link sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aNAK.jpg)

Is it Possible in android? if possible please help me how to apply.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working on a LUT applier library which eases the use of LUT images in Android. It uses the algorythm below, but I'd like to enhance it in the future for optimising memory usage. Now it also guesses the color axes of the LUT:
https://github.com/dntks/easyLUT/wiki

Your LUT image has the red-green-blue color dimension in an other order than what I've been used to, so I had to change the order of when getting the lutIndex (at `getLutIndex()`).
Please check my edited answer:

```
final static int X_DEPTH = 16;
final static int Y_DEPTH = 16; //One little square has 16x16 pixels in it
final static int ROW_DEPTH = 4;
final static int COLUMN_DEPTH = 4; // the image consists of 4x4 little squares
final static int COLOR_DISTORTION = 16; // 256*256*256 => 256 no distortion, 64*64*64 => 256 dividied by 4 = 64, 16x16x16 => 256 dividied by 16 = 16

private Bitmap applyLutToBitmap(Bitmap src, Bitmap lutBitmap) {
    int lutWidth = lutBitmap.getWidth();
    int lutColors[] = new int[lutWidth * lutBitmap.getHeight()];
    lutBitmap.getPixels(lutColors, 0, lutWidth, 0, 0, lutWidth, lutBitmap.getHeight());

    int mWidth = src.getWidth();
    int mHeight = src.getHeight();
    int[] pix = new int[mWidth * mHeight];
    src.getPixels(pix, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

    int R, G, B;
    for (int y = 0; y < mHeight; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < mWidth; x++) {
            int index = y * mWidth + x;
            int r = ((pix[index] >> 16) & 0xff) / COLOR_DISTORTION;
            int g = ((pix[index] >> 8) & 0xff) / COLOR_DISTORTION;
            int b = (pix[index] & 0xff) / COLOR_DISTORTION;

            int lutIndex = getLutIndex(lutWidth, r, g, b);

            R = ((lutColors[lutIndex] >> 16) & 0xff);
            G = ((lutColors[lutIndex] >> 8) & 0xff);
            B = ((lutColors[lutIndex]) & 0xff);
            pix[index] = 0xff000000 | (R << 16) | (G << 8) | B;
        }
    Bitmap filteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth, mHeight, src.getConfig());
    filteredBitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
    return filteredBitmap;
}

//the magic happens here
private int getLutIndex(int lutWidth, int redDepth, int greenDepth, int blueDepth) {
    int lutX = (greenDepth % ROW_DEPTH) * X_DEPTH + blueDepth;
    int lutY = (greenDepth / COLUMN_DEPTH) * Y_DEPTH + redDepth;
    return lutY * lutWidth + lutX;
}
```

Comment: sorry i didn't check the answer from here. at last i tried this one also but getting ArrayIndexOutofBound Exception at this line R = ((lutColors[lutIndex] >> 16) & 0xff);

Comment: Hi, I've edited my answer, finally I could test it on a device as well ;) the main difference was that your LUT image has the colors in an other order than my LUT images

Comment: thank you for reply.. i think it is not the problem.. if you don't mind can you upload your LUT to check the difference between your LUT and mine...

Comment: I've updated the code to fit your LUT, please check it!

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Please accept the answer, if it did. If LUT image is resized in different devices, place it in the drawable-nodpi folder.

Comment: No.. i tested in two devices(samsung s4 and lenevo a7000).. it is working on lenevo but not working on s4.. it means filters getting like with shade..

Comment: In which resource folder did you put your LUT image?

Comment: I've written in several places; you should place it to drawable-nodpi, so then the system wouldn't resize it.

Comment: i am facing another issue now. when we apply the filter using above code using lut . its effect to the image but with effect i am getting oil marks. here is the original pic link http://imgur.com/W7AOJkv and result pic link http://imgur.com/w4Kfv0t. please zoom and observe difference you will clearly notice oil marks. how to avoid these?

Comment: I suppose its because the reduce of the color depth. You have very little LUTs (16x16x16) =4096, while the original image uses 256*256*256 colors (16,777,216) which is 4096 times more colors to use. This way similar colors become the same color in the filtered image. I'd suggest to use larger LUTs (at least 64x64x64), this small luts can be used only for small images efficiently.

Comment: sorry for late..  small images means can you tell me the range and how could we generate large luts based on small luts?

Comment: From small luts you can't generate larger ones as the information is already lost. I don't know who gave you the LUT data, but usually its exported from photo applications like Photoshop, Corel etc. So you'll need to export larger LUTs from the original source.
If you'd like a cleaner understanding of luts, please read through my other answer you've already seen.

Comment: what's the range for small Luts?

Comment: Your image is 64*64 pixels (representing a 16 dimensional lut cube), which is considerably small. An 512*512 image represents a 64 dimensional lut cube, which is enough in most cases. A 4096*4096 image would cause a lossless cube, but that's a huge image to be stored in memory, so usually not good for android.

Comment: hi abbath,  i need your help again. i tried 8*8 lut also but result is same like 4*4 lut. then i tried below code its working but when i tried to CROP the filtered image then result is too noise. i tried to find out solution but failed. if you have any idea or any alternative solution please suggest me or guide me. till now it takes too much time so please help me..

Comment: Could you upload your 8x8 lut somewhere so i could have a check on it. Also what kind of "CROP" is what you use?

Comment: here is the 8*8 image http://imgur.com/JfPc5si. i used below library for cropping https://github.com/rameshkec85/AndroidCropMoveScaleImage. here my logic is "Bitmap bit = ivcropimageview.getCroppedImage();" when i tried to set this bitmap to imageview then its displaying as too noise.

Comment: Please raise an other question for this, as too much comments are here.

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417152/images-getting-as-too-noise-when-applying-filters-in-android

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would process an image with  RenderScript's ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT;
import android.renderscript.Type;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView1;
    RenderScript mRs;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Bitmap mLutBitmap;
    ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT mScriptlut;
    Bitmap mOutputBitmap;
    Allocation mAllocIn;
    Allocation mAllocOut;
    Allocation mAllocCube;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mRs = RenderScript.create(this);
        Background background = new Background();
        background.execute();
    }

    class Background extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (mRs == null) {
                mRs = RenderScript.create(MainActivity.this);
            }
            if (mBitmap == null) {
                mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.bugs);

                mOutputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mBitmap.getConfig());

                mAllocIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRs, mBitmap);
                mAllocOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRs, mOutputBitmap);
            }
            if (mLutBitmap == null) {
                mLutBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.drawable.dawizfe);
                int w = mLutBitmap.getWidth();
                int h = mLutBitmap.getHeight();
                int redDim = w / 4;
                int greenDim = h / 4;
                int blueDim = 16;
                android.renderscript.Type.Builder tb = new Type.Builder(mRs, Element.U8_4(mRs));
                tb.setX(redDim);
                tb.setY(greenDim);
                tb.setZ(blueDim);
                Type t = tb.create();
                mAllocCube = Allocation.createTyped(mRs, t);
                int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
                int[] lut = new int[w * h];
                mLutBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
                int i = 0;
                for (int r = 0; r < redDim; r++) {
                   for (int g = 0; g < greenDim; g++) {
                        for (int b = 0; b < blueDim; b++) {
                            int gdown = g / 4;
                            int gright = g % 4;
                            lut[i] = pixels[b + r * w + gdown * w * redDim + gright * blueDim];
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
//                This is an identity 3D LUT
//                i = 0;
//                for (int r = 0; r < redDim; r++) {
//                    for (int g = 0; g < greenDim; g++) {
//                        for (int b = 0; b < blueDim; b++) {
//                            int bcol = (b * 255) / blueDim;
//                            int gcol = (g * 255) / greenDim;
//                            int rcol = (r * 255) / redDim;
//                            lut[i] = bcol | (gcol << 8) | (rcol << 16);
//                            i++;
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
                mAllocCube.copyFromUnchecked(lut);
            }
            if (mScriptlut == null) {
                mScriptlut = ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT.create(mRs, Element.U8_4(mRs));

            }
            mScriptlut.setLUT(mAllocCube);
            mScriptlut.forEach(mAllocIn, mAllocOut);

            mAllocOut.copyTo(mOutputBitmap);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            imageView1.setImageBitmap(mOutputBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for late reply.. i tried this but i think its not correct... just i replaced drawables with http://imgur.com/W7AOJkv and http://imgur.com/Ai2k1PV , after i implemented your code with these drawables then the result is http://imgur.com/OLMXKHf.  but actual output should be like this http://imgur.com/OqGHMVU...  do you have any idea? please guide me..

Comment: The unpack logic for you image was wrong I fixed it

Comment: its working only for some LUTs. what changes to be made for remaining filters ?

Comment: it is not working for all devices too. for ex : i checked in two devices like samsung s4 and lenevo a7000. in lenevo lutBitmap width and height is 64*64 and coming to s4 it is 96*96.so am getting arrayindexoutofbound exception in s4 at this line lut[i] = pixels[b + r * w + gdown * w * redDim + gright * blueDim];. please check it..

Comment: For the LUT image size problem: place the LUT image in the 'drawable-nodpi' folder!

Comment: The simplest expression lut[i] = pixels[b + r * w + gdown * w * redDim + gright * blueDim]; i could find on the internet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

u can go through this, hope it will help you to get the right process.

photo is the main bitmap here.

mLut3D is the array of LUT images stored in drawable

```
    RenderScript mRs;
    Bitmap mLutBitmap, mBitmap;
    ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT mScriptlut;
    Bitmap mOutputBitmap;
    Allocation mAllocIn;
    Allocation mAllocOut;
    Allocation mAllocCube;
    int mFilter = 0;

mRs = RenderScript.create(yourActivity.this);
public Bitmap filterapply() {
        int redDim, greenDim, blueDim;
        int w, h;
        int[] lut;

        if (mScriptlut == null) {
            mScriptlut = ScriptIntrinsic3DLUT.create(mRs, Element.U8_4(mRs));
        }
         if (mBitmap == null) {
         mBitmap = photo;
}
        mOutputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap.getWidth(),
                mBitmap.getHeight(), mBitmap.getConfig());

        mAllocIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRs, mBitmap);
        mAllocOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(mRs, mOutputBitmap);
        // }

        mLutBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                mLut3D[mFilter]);
        w = mLutBitmap.getWidth();
        h = mLutBitmap.getHeight();
        redDim = w / h;
        greenDim = redDim;
        blueDim = redDim;
        int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
        lut = new int[w * h];
        mLutBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
        int i = 0;

        for (int r = 0; r < redDim; r++) {
            for (int g = 0; g < greenDim; g++) {
                int p = r + g * w;
                for (int b = 0; b < blueDim; b++) {
                    lut[i++] = pixels[p + b * h];
                }
            }
        }

        Type.Builder tb = new Type.Builder(mRs, Element.U8_4(mRs));
        tb.setX(redDim).setY(greenDim).setZ(blueDim);
        Type t = tb.create();
        mAllocCube = Allocation.createTyped(mRs, t);
        mAllocCube.copyFromUnchecked(lut);

        mScriptlut.setLUT(mAllocCube);
        mScriptlut.forEach(mAllocIn, mAllocOut);

        mAllocOut.copyTo(mOutputBitmap);
        return mOutputBitmap;
    }
```

you increase the mFilter value to get different filter effect with different LUT images, you have, check it out.

you can go through the this link on github for more help, i got the answer from here:- 
https://github.com/RenderScript/RsLutDemo

hope it will help

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for help. This Github link really works.

Comment: Hi Shubham, in the RsLutDemo, do you know how do the drawable-nodpi/lut_bleach.png come from? Any tool to generate these files? Thanks a lot.

Comment: hello A.TNG , actually LUT images are created by graphics designer, you can ask them for filters LUT images, they just need to study for that. you may also go through this [link](http://blogs.adobe.com/richardcurtis/2014/09/19/creativefriday-creating-3d-luts-in-photoshop-for-video-grading-and-image-enhancement/) or some other like that.