# How to apply *.cube Lut in android bitmaps?

Tags: java, android, colors, cube, lookup-tables

I have lut files in .cube format.
How to use those `.cube` files in android for applying the filter effects?

I am doing sample in android, applying the filter effects for images.

I know how to use the lut's to apply the filters but i don't have any idea how to use .cube files to apply the filter effects in android.

Comment: What do you think describes your question best? Is it too broad, too unclear or are you asking us to recommend a library deal with .cube files? In other words: Your question needs to be improved or someone will decide that question for you. You should probably split your research into smaller parts: "how do I read .cube files in android/java", then "how do I apply color corrections from a multidimensional table to bitmaps" (do you even mean the `Bitmap` class?). Those may even have answers here,.

Comment: Can you export your .cube file into an image LUT instead? For image LUTs I have an answer how to use! Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910234/how-to-use-lut-with-javascript/25252446#25252446) it contains android code as well.

Comment: Hi Abbath,i am tried your code refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905539/how-to-apply-color-lut-to-bitmap-images-for-filter-effects-in-android. It works fine for first time again i am doing cropping for the filtered image and apply filter it results noise image.please help me for this.Thanks in advance